# one account, multitple subscription, one invoice per subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

I've been trying to solve the problem for 2 days, but I don't know if it's still worth trying, because I don't know if stripe offers such solutions at all.

In my project, one user may have several businesses that have different company data Vat-number etc. A separate subscription can be purchased for each business (it can also have different card data in each subscription), I would like one user to be able to have several subscriptions independent of each other, does anyone know if such a thing in stripe can be implemented and how?

I have already tried creating a completely new product with a new name before creating a payment session, but stripe still shows me after generating the payment link that the user already has a plan.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Stripe has a setting that restricts customers to 1 subscription per email : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/limit-subscriptions. If you want to allow a customer to have multiple subscriptions per email, you should disable that setting.

However, you should keep in mind that with Payment Links, a new Customer object will typically be created for every Subscription. Stripe does not detect that a Customer already exists for that email and create a Subscription under that Customer object for you.

If you want to be able to create multiple Subscriptions under a unique Customer object, you can consider :

- The Buy Button which allows you to pass in an existing Customer id : https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links/buy-button#pass-an-existing-customer
- Building your own client-server integration for Subscriptions with Checkout Sessions : https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart

Both of the above options require you to implement some logic to determine whether to create / reuse an existing Customer object id.